# error updating inside js (tabbed panel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

When i click on the link button, it does not show the data from DB... if the part i am updating from DB is outside the tabbed panel then it works fine...i guess something is wrong because of the js(tabbed panel)...any ideas??

**ASPX CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var hh;
        var left;

        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                //Default Action
                hh = '<div id="convertThis">' + $("#convertThis").html() + '</div>';
                var tab1 = $("#convertThis").advancedTabs({
                    tabPosition: 'top',
                    visibleTabItem: 3,
                    whereAmI: false,
                    width:728,
                    hideTabs: true
                });
            }
        }

    </script>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMainContent" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="barbig left padright">
      <div class="ccs2008header">
        <h4 id="h4header" runat="server" class="css2008fontstyle"></h4>
      </div>  

      <div id="convertThis">
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <div rel="divUpdatePanel" >
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDefinitions" runat="server" OnClientClick="LinkButtonDefinitions_Click">Definitions</asp:LinkButton></div>
                        <div rel="divUpdatePanel">Employees</div>
                        <div rel="divUpdatePanel" >Family</div>
                        <div rel="d" >Home Town</div>
                        <div rel="e">Other Than Home Town</div>
                        <div rel="f" >Admissibility</div>
                        <div rel="g" >Types Of LTC</div>
                        <div rel="h" >Block Period</div>
                        <div rel="i">Entitlement</div>
                        <div rel="j" >Advance</div>
                        <div rel="l" >Adjustment of advance</div>
                        <div rel="n" >Reimbursement</div>
                        <div rel="o" >Carry Over & Forfeiture of claim</div>
                        <div rel="o" >Relaxations & Interpretations</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divs">
                        <div id="divUpdatePanel" runat="server">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
        </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonDefinitions" />
        </Triggers>

       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
 Public Sub loadContent(ByVal PageName As String)

        Dim _con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LeaveDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim _da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PageHeader,PageContent FROM PageKeeper WHERE PageName='" & PageName & "'", _con)
        Dim _table As New DataTable

        Try
            _con.Open()
            _da.Fill(_table)
            _con.Close()
            _con.Dispose()
            With _table.Rows(0)
                h4header.InnerText = .Item(0)
                divUpdatePanel.InnerHtml = .Item(1)
                Me.Title = .Item(0)
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            divUpdatePanel.InnerText = "No Data Found"
        Finally
            _con.Close()
            _con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub LinkButtonDefinitions_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButtonDefinitions.Click
        loadContent("Definitions")
    End Sub
```

Comment: i do not get any error...the data i am fetching from the DB does not show up inside the div...but if i move the div out of the tabbed panel...it starts working.

Comment: Why so many down votes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do not initialize the `pageLoad` no where in your code.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_endRequest(pageLoad);
```

This pageLoad is not a function that automatically called from UpdatePanel, you need to initialize that on `javascript` part. Actually is not a know function, so I guess that you copy paste this code from somewhere with out this part.

Comment: thanks for the reply...but i think i have this `function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
` in my js which is what you are saying??correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user1150440 You do not have the above code ! did you see it ? Its not the same as yours...